# How to query a name who has a letter (for example K) in their job and their salary is bigger than a certain number

Tags: mysql, xampp

*That's the sample of the table:*

```
+--------+-------+--------+
|  name  |  job  | salary |
+--------+-------+--------+
|  DAVE  | CLERK |  1500  |
|  ADAM  |MANAGER|  3000  |
+--------+-------+--------+
```

**Who are the ones who have the letter "K" in their job and their salary is at least 500?**

This is what I tried:

```
SELECT name
FROM table
WHERE (salary >= 500) AND (job LIKE '%K%')
```

Comment: Your code looks fine (the parentheses around the conditions are not needed). Are you having a particular problem with it? You did not ask a question here.

Comment: You should not use reserved word like [table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-T) for a table name  ...

Comment: @GMB I tried several times and nothing happened. (I thought my code was bad.) But as you said, it should work so I tried again. Maybe I just misspelt something. My code is working. Sorry for that, I should have looked in more detail.

Comment: The query looks ok: https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=a1c7d8e7f32b0356ddfde0483a9fd62b&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57